# List all combinations of 'select 10 different numbers from 1-100'

Tags: combinations

It is known that there exists C(100,10) possibilities of **selecting 10 different numbers from 1 to 100**. each possibility is a combination like [1, 2,..., 10] or [2,3,...,11], or [11, 22, 33, .., 99, 100], as long as the 10 numbers are different.

How to list all the combinations by programming??
I don't want to write 10 Loops, python or c preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using python and [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

**Warning** - Printing will take a long time

```
for i in itertools.combinations(xrange(1,101),10):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, [Yujie Liu](http://liuyujie.com) came up this idea. Using pure iteration.

```
# select n diff numbers from min - max
def traceArr(arr, min, max, n):
    if n > 0:
        for i in range(min, max-n+2):
            arr1 = arr[:]
            arr1.append(i)
            traceArr(arr1, i+1, max, n-1)
    elif n == 0:
        print arr    

# Demo, select 5 diff numbers from 1-10
traceArr([], 1, 10, 5);
```